# Close Votes on Meta

Tags: support, reputation, vote-to-close

I just discovered I can cast a [close vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170241/171964) on meta at 288 reputation, even though the privileges list marks it at 3k.

Is this a bug?

- I do have the "Close Vote" privilege on SO.
- The question was my own, can I always vote to close my own questions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're able to cast close votes on your own questions [at 250 reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes).